# weird stuff with asp.net button CSS class

Tags: asp.net, css

I have the following button:

```
<Club:RolloverButton runat="server" ValidationGroup="Login1" Text="Login" ID="LoginButton"
                                            CommandName="Login" CssClass="links"  />

.links {
    display: block;
    width: 96px;
    padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
    background: #A53602;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

When this button shows up the first time it shows the style correctly, however if I hover my mouse over this button the layout turns into a standard button, why is that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first try this/
    css:

```
div.blabla input.links {display: block;...}
```

try that class with normal asp.net button/ 
and if it works correctly, club kit does not give you any flexibility/
and then check your buttons hover class from developer view or firebug/

if your button has "links" class, give your every parameter !important/
its something like this/

```
...
display: block !important;

width: 96px !important;

padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px !important;
...
```

and if it does not workin either way, give class "links" to  your buttons hover/

```
.links:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 96px;
    ...}
```